# After a mistake in Texmaker, it has to be restarted

Tags: errors, texmaker

I am using Texmaker to write my thesis. Whenever I make a mistake, let's say misspell a command, the program stops working. It means I have to restart Texmaker. It so frustrating.

I was wondering if someone has some idea for the reason.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Amir. [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. What version of Texmaker are you using? Does it stop when compiling or right after you typed the misspelled command?

Comment: Huh? Can you elaborate on that? If LaTeX encounters a mistyped macro sequence it will stop or ask the user. TeXmaker should not be influenced by this but rather should catch that LaTeX has encountered a problem.

Comment: Was it taking too long to compile? An MWE will tell us a lot of things about this problem, e.g., if there are infinite loops or the like. :)

Comment: Is it because the compiling program loses response? Next time this happen, try the "stop process" button (little red cross) on the left of log window. It should help.

Comment: Thanks everybody,
Francis's suggestion solved my problem. I really appreciated. you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

If the compiling process loses response, simply hit the "stop process" button (little red cross) on the left side of Messages/Log window, the compiling process will immediately stop.

The computer I am using doesn't have Texmaker installed so I will use a screen shot from Texmaker official site to demonstrate:

[image]